# How to let the user decide when to stop a for loop from counting (C programming)

Tags: c

I'm trying to build a program that counts the number of times a/b/c is entered and prints the results. Right now I can only enter one of the three letters 4 times using for loop. My question is, can something be done to let the user(me) decide when the loop should stop? Maybe like pressing 'Z' then the counting variable 'i' stops counting.

I actually know a method of achieving this using while loops and the function getchar but I'm trying to find different ways of doing it.

```
  main()
  {
    int i;
    char a[10];

    int aCount=0;
    int bCount=0;
    int cCount=0;

    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
      scanf("%s", &a[i]);

      switch(a[i])
      {
         case 'A':
         case 'a':
           aCount++;
         break;
         case 'B':
         case 'b':
           bCount++;
         break;
         case 'C':
         case 'c':
           cCount++;
         break;
         default:
           puts("Mxm choose A, B or C");
         break;
       }
    }
    printf("\nA - %d\nB - %d\nC - %d", aCount,bCount,cCount);
  }
```

//Using while loops

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){


int aCount=0;
int bCount=0;
int cCount=0;

int x;

char a[10];
a[0] = 'f';

while((x = getchar()) != a[0]){

    switch(x){

    case 'A':
    case 'a':
    aCount++;
    break;

    case 'B':
    case 'b':
    bCount++;
    break;

    case 'C':
    case 'c':
    cCount++;
    break;



 }

}

    printf("\nA - %d\nB - %d\nC - %d", aCount,bCount,cCount);

}
```

Comment: So where is the `while` loop method you have made? If that code is working, should the question be on CodeReview? I would say this code can be fairly easily adapted with more `case` statements, and with `for` loop replaced by `while` loop. You should also replace `char a[10];` with something more sensible, such as a single `char`  and follow that through.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &a[i]);` should probably be `scanf("%c", &a[i]);`

Comment: also `switch(tolower(a[i]))` saves a lot of cases.

Comment: I rarely downvote answers but these are all terrible.

Comment: Check my edited post //Using while loops, you press f to stop @WeatherVane

Comment: I think %s is correct @Jean-FrançoisFabre because I'm basically storing a string with one character, I tried using %c and it's giving problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are currently doing `for (i = 0; i<4; i++)` it will only run through your loop 4 times since you are checking to see if `i` is less than `4`. You could set `i < #some larger number` and it would allow the user to enter more choices but wouldn't be infinite. You could also do something like the following where it will check to see if `i` does not equal `z`. Once it does equal `z` it will exit the loop.

**Disclaimer: While this appears to work I'm unsure of the implications it may have as I am not much of a C programmer.**

*Edit: Per the suggestions of @yano and @Weather Vane, I've changed it to use `scanf` instead of `getchar` which will help remove new line characters.  I've also changed/initialized i as `char i = -1;`*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
  char i = -1;
  int aCount=0;
  int bCount=0;
  int cCount=0;
  puts("Please choose A, B, C, or Z to exit.");
  for(;i != 'z';) {
    scanf(" %c", &i)
    i = tolower(i);
    switch(i){
      case 'a':
        aCount++;
        break;

      case 'b':
        bCount++;
        break;

      case 'c':
        cCount++;
        break;

      default:
          puts("Mxm choose A, B or C, or Z to quit.");
          break;

    }
  }
  printf("\nA - %d\nB - %d\nC - %d\n", aCount,bCount,cCount);
}
```

Comment: `scanf` would be a better choice as the newlines can be easily filtered out with `scanf(" %c", &ch)` a point missed in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this without the use of `switch`. A simple `do-while` loop and `if-else` statements. If you wish to check for more than 10 elements you could either change the macro definition.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int aCount=0;
    int bCount=0;
    int cCount=0;

    char ch;
    char temp;
    do{

          scanf(" %c", &temp);
          if(a[i]=='a'||a[i]=='A')aCount++;
          else if(a[i]=='b'||a[i]=='B')bCount++;
          else if(a[i]=='c'||a[i]=='C')cCount++;

          printf("Continue??");
          scanf(" %c", &ch);

    }while(ch != 'z');
     printf("\nA - %d\nB - %d\nC - %d", aCount,bCount,cCount);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What is the array for? Suppose user went [up to 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to_eleven)? That would break the array.

Comment: `fflush(stdin); scanf("%c", &ch);` ==> `scanf(" %c", &ch);` note the space which filters out leading whitespace.

Comment: You missed the essential space, and, there are two instances. And why do you still have that array? What is it for?

Comment: The array is ...i think..maybe because the OP had used it.  This could be done without an array too. Use a `temp` variable.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure there are more  "correct" ways of doing it, but simply letting the continuation of the loop depend on a specific input should do the trick, as such:

```
  int main()
  {
    int i;
    char a = '?';

    int aCount=0;
    int bCount=0;
    int cCount=0;

    while(a != 'q' && a != 'Q')
    {
      scanf("%c", &a);

      switch(a)
      {
         case 'A':
         case 'a':
           aCount++;
         break;
         case 'B':
         case 'b':
           bCount++;
         break;
         case 'C':
         case 'c':
           cCount++;
         break;
         default:
           puts("Mxm choose A, B, C or Q to quit.");
         break;
       }
    }
    printf("\nA - %d\nB - %d\nC - %d", aCount,bCount,cCount);
  }
```

Comment: @WeatherVane Indeed I did. It was not supposed to be pretty, just to show the principle. and it does work, so I don't really know that the neg rep is all about.

Comment: The code issues the `default` failure prompt even when you enter a valid character, because it fails to dispose of the newline following the input, which is picked up on the next loop. However it neglects to prompt what should be entered in the first place. Also the `main()` signature is obsolete. I say - if you can't post a pretty answer, don't post at all.

Comment: So? That was not the point was it?Obviously it will have to be restructured if it is to work as intended, but that was not the issue. The issue was how the user can decide to break the loop, and this is one solution. And sure, I've made a typo,but if that is the issue, then write what, and do be polite about it, otherwise, as you'd say, don't comment at all.